# What settings in Chrome am I missing to get the prompt for new questions in StackOverflow?

Tags: google-chrome

What settings in Chrome am I missing to get the prompt for new questions in StackOverflow?

If I sit on the [new questions tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c#?tab=newest) on one machine, the browser will recognize that new questions are coming in.  I will get a `(#) Newest Unanswered Questions - StackOverflow` on the browser tab, and on the page a bar will appear saying `(#) new questions available`, and they will increment as new questions show up.

On another of my machines however, I do not get this functionality at all.

*Is it a chrome permission setting that I'm missing?*  I have opened everything up and I cant seem to reproduce it.  *Or could it be some java control that I dont have installed?*

Comment: On that other machine: Are you using the same browser (version) too? Are you using any type of proxy?

Comment: Great question, thank you, its the same version and no proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, the answer is that I was just looking at two different pages, one with the functionality, and the other without.

Apparently, if I am on the questions tagged page:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23?sort=newest`

I get the notifications that new questions have come in.

If however I am on the unanswered newest *tab*:

`http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c%23?tab=newest`

The notifications arent available.

The indication is that one page title says "Newest Unanswered Questions" (no notification) and the other says "Newest 'c# Questions" (with notification)